# php imap_fetchmime is missed on 5.3.10 / 5.3.15

Tags: php, imap

PHP imap_fetchmime is not available on PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 on my ubuntu and PHP 5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch  on my mac.

on https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchmime.php, imap_fetchmime is available (PHP 5 >= 5.3.6)

Could anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 0):

> This extension requires the c-client library to be installed. Grab the latest version from ftp://ftp.cac.washington.edu/imap/ and compile it.

http://php.net/manual/en/imap.requirements.php

Have you checked (via `phpinfo()`) that the IMAP extension is enabled?

Comment: thanks. My IMAP version is the latest 2007e with SSL supported. Before you put this comment, have you ever tried 'imap_fetchmime' on your php environment?

Comment: @rainmore No, why should I? It's not about my environment where that should work – it's your server where it should work.

Comment: Hi, I've tried 3 machines for this issues. Please don't waste your time if you don't know the answer. thanks.